# SVG line resize issues

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, line

Currently, I am creating an editor and I am dynamically creating scalable lines.
The goal then is to be able to resize/drag and drop smoothly.

Inspiration got from
[Slides](http://www.slides.com)
[image: slides.com lines]

Here is my current prototype [Stackblitz prototype](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jt6zh3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Dragging - I solved with drag and drop from CDK by adding calculation of scale in `onDragEnded`

My current issues:

1. As you can see currently my calculation and mental model of how this should work is bad - at some point in time, I lose the line. Can you advise what I am missing? (maybe my resizers have bad position)
2. I am not sure if I am drawing this arrow properly in SVG?
3. I am not sure if I should use viewBox?

Maybe there is a library for doing this and that I am unaware of.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your marker is fine.  I think it's a bit odd that you are mixing SVG and HTML. I believe you would find it a **lot** easier to do everything inside an SVG.

Comment: i think something is throwing in some extra x and y values in your code which is the cause of shifting in the viewbox on dragging

Answer (score 1):

I believe the core of your issue is rooted in your `p1` and `p2` calculations... essentially, the calculation, is never letting the axes reach `0` which creates an offset for the next iteration of the calculation.

A crude POC is outlined below to ensure this offset is handled... but... there is likely a more elegant way to write this algorithm.

This POC will at least demonstrate the concept.

```
if (this.dragPointActive === 'p1') {
    if (block.x2 - block.x1 < 0) {
      // if x2 hasn't reached 0
      // use current x2 value to complete left calc
      if (block.x2 < 0) {
        block.left += block.x2;
        block.x2 = 0;
      }
      block.x1 += deltaX;
    } else {
      block.x2 -= deltaX;
      block.left += deltaX;
      // if x1 hasn't reached 0
      if (block.x1 < 0) {
        block.x1 = 0;
      }
    }

    if (block.y2 - block.y1 < 0) {
      // if y2 hasn't reached 0
      // use current y2 value to complete left calc
      if (block.y2 < 0) {
        block.top += block.y2;
        block.y2 = 0;
      }
      block.y1 += deltaY;
    } else {
      block.y2 -= deltaY;
      block.top += deltaY;
      // if y1 hasn't reached 0
      if (block.y1 < 0) {
        block.y1 = 0;
      }
    }
  } else if (this.dragPointActive === 'p2') {
    if (block.x2 - block.x1 < 0) {
      block.x1 -= deltaX;
      block.left += deltaX;
      // if x2 hasn't reached 0
      if (block.x2 < 0) {
        block.x2 = 0;
      }
    } else {
      // if x1 hasn't reached 0
      // use current x1 value to complete left calc
      if (block.x1 < 0) {
        block.left += block.x1;
        block.x1 = 0;
      }
      block.x2 += deltaX;
    }

    if (block.y2 - block.y1 < 0) {
      block.y1 -= deltaY;
      block.top += deltaY;
      // if y2 hasn't reached 0
      if (block.y2 < 0) {
        block.y2 = 0;
      }
    } else {
      // if y1 hasn't reached 0
      // use current y1 value to complete top calc
      if (block.y1 < 0) {
        block.top += block.y1;
        block.y1 = 0;
      }
      block.y2 += deltaY;
    }
  }
```

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-davn1v?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hi @Marshal, thank you very much for your answer. Your addition really improves how my not-so-good solution is working - how I see it is only one thing left there for me to understand - how to fix horizontal view when I come in that place. I am same looking for a better algorithm because I believe that there is a way better way to make this work...If you find the will or desire to maybe suggest something else please do it, in any case, I am very grateful for your answer